# SQL (access) Where date is within 6 months of a different date field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using SQL within Access which i have never done before, I do not have another SQL option at this job.

I have `Table1.Service_Date`  and `Table2.Service_Date`

I am trying to create a where statement that includes `Table2.Service_Date` if it occurs 6 months or less before `Table1.Service_date`.

Comment: You could do something like `WHERE DATEDIFF("d", Table1.Service_date, Table2.Service_Date) < 180`

Comment: please include additional table structure information and sample data in your question for eventual future reference.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is an **inner join** statement in order to link data that fit your range.

```
SELECT *
    FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN on Table2 t2 ON ((DATEADD(t1.Service_Date, -6, MONTH) <= t2.Service_Date)
                                AND (t1.Service_Date >= t2.Service_Date))
    -- any WHERE statement to filter the dates    
;
```

You may have different needs for the `<=` or `>=` conditions, so adapt the solution to fit your needs.

Comment: That is not Access SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It will be:

```
Where Table2.Service_Date <= DateAdd("m", -6, Table1.Service_Date)
```

or:

```
Where DateAdd("m", 6, Table2.Service_Date) <= Table1.Service_Date
```

Which to choose, depends on how to handle *dates of ultimo* - 28, 29, 30, and 31.

If neither fits, use this function:

```
Public Function DateAddMonth( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByVal intIncrement As Integer = 1, _
  Optional ByVal booLeapYearIgnore As Boolean = True) _
  As Date

' Add intIncrement number of months to datDate.
' If datDate is ultimo, return date will also be ultimo.
'
' 1999-10-21, Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, Copenhagen

  Dim datDateNext As Date
  Dim booUltimo As Boolean

  ' No specific error handling.
  On Error Resume Next

  ' Add one day.
  datDateNext = DateAdd("d", 1, datDate)
  ' If datDate is ultimo, next day will be the first of the next month.
  booUltimo = (Day(datDateNext) = 1)

  If (Not booUltimo) And booLeapYearIgnore Then
    ' Regard February 28 as ultimo also for leap years.
    If (Month(datDate) = 2) And (Day(datDate) = 28) Then
      ' Add one more day.
      datDateNext = DateAdd("d", 1, datDateNext)
      booUltimo = True
    End If
  End If

  If booUltimo Then
    ' Add intIncrement number of months to the first of next month.
    datDateNext = DateAdd("m", intIncrement, datDateNext)
    ' Decrement one day.
    ' As datDate is ultimo, the month will be decremented too.
    datDateNext = DateAdd("d", -1, datDateNext)
  Else
    ' Add intIncrement number of months to datDate.
    datDateNext = DateAdd("m", intIncrement, datDate)
  End If

  DateAddMonth = datDateNext

End Function
```

and either of these:

```
Where Table2.Service_Date <= DateAddMonth(Table1.Service_Date, -6)

Where DateAddMonth(Table2.Service_Date, 6) <= Table1.Service_Date
```